# SpriteKit Horizontal Tile Map

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to put together a tile-map for a game background. The tiling works in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape, I get a blank screen.

The code is listed below:

```
-(SKNode *)createBackgroundNode
{
    SKNode *backgroundNode = [SKNode node];

    for (int nodeCount = 0; nodeCount < 20; nodeCount++) {

        NSString *backgroundImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Background%02d", nodeCount+1];
        SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: backgroundImageName];


        node.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        node.position = CGPointMake(nodeCount * 320.0f, 0.0f);
        //node.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, nodeCount * 64.0f);


        [backgroundNode addChild: node];
    }

    return backgroundNode;
}
```

Basically it is a game that is only played in landscape mode, and I need the tiles to be placed horizontally one after the other to create the map.

Any help with this is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear, my game only supports landscape orientation. When my iPhone is in landscape orientation, I am unable to see my map. If I play with the settings in XCode and allow the app to be in portrait orientation, I am able to see the tile map going across the screen; however, this is NOT what I want and I only did that to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Switching screen orientation while using tile maps is not advisable. Once you have loaded your tile map, you would be better off staying in the selected orientation mode. AT least that has been my own experience using the Tiled app.